# Error:Execution failed for task :app:transformJackWithJackForDebug - Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-jack-and-jill

My `gradle` is like bellow :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xx.xx.xx"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //Slider
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    //Rx
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
    // Web Libs
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'

}
```

And here :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        //Slider
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.10.+'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

But when I run my project say me `BUILD FAILED` and show me bellow message :

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem :

Module gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xx.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //Slider
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    // Web Libs
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    //Rx
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:0.16.1'

}
```

project gradle :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        //Slider
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.10.+'
        //Lambda
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: can you explain what you changed ?

Answer (score 4):

Remove jackOption from defaultConfig in build.gradle

Add following lines in Application gradle

```
dependencies {

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'

classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.3'

}
```

And add following line in build.gradle  as below:

```
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
```

Hope this will help.